# just installed 12.10 but cant find disk utility

Tags: 12.10, disk, disk-utility

I just installed 12.10, but can't find the `Disk Utility`.
Disk Utility show as installed.
I even uninstalled and reinstalled it, but still can't find. The best I can find is `Disks`, almost but no testing features.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + T (open Terminal) then `palimpsest` command opens it. What happens when you try this?

Comment: @TomBrossman I'm using 12.10 and the command now is `gnome-disks`.

Comment: For you that is voting for closing as "Too localized", it is not. Check my answer.

Comment: @EricCarvalho You are correct, nice catch! I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The tool you're looking for is `Disks` (`gnome-disks` in terminal), indeed. Press the "two-cog" buttons and you'll find the Test/SMART and Benchmark options.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on *Dash Home* type *Disk Utility* you will find the Disk Utility Icon, select it, will show Storage Devices connected to your system. Select any drive and will show you options like *Check Filesystem* , *Edit Partition* etc.